# How to import all python file and there method from a project folder

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

Here is my python project structure:

```
`-- Test
|-- searchservice
|   `-- Applandingsearch.py
`-- test.py
```

In Applandingsearch.py, my code is :

```
class Applandingsearch(unittest.TestCase):

def test_responsestatus_correct(self):
    self.assertEqual(statuscode, 200)

def test_responsetime_lessthan800ms(self):

    self.assertLessEqual(responsetime, 0.8)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In test.py, I want to import the Applandingsearch, my code in test.py is :

```
from Test.searchservice import * 

if __name__ == '__main__':

   suite = unittest.TestSuite()

   tests = [Applandingsearch("test_responsestatus_correct")]

   suite.addTests(tests)
```

When I run test.py, the console report "    **Applandingsearch("test_responseresult_correct"),
NameError: name 'Applandingsearch' is not defined**
"

How can I import all the method in Applandingsearch.py?
if I write :

```
from Test.searchservice.Applandingsearch import Applandingsearch
or
from Test.searchservice.Applandingsearch import *
```

It can run success, but if I have many files, I have to import all of them, it is too long.

Can someone give some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this artcle. https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/